# spark sql dataframe write to S3 failed with "Error closing multipart upload"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

So I have a pyspark job that runs on AWS EMR cluster with EMR 5.11.0, Spark 2.2.1.
The spark job needs to write a pretty big data frame (~100GB) to S3.
At first I tried writing directly to S3 like follows:

```
df = .... # calculate the data frame
df.write.mode("append").parquet("s3://...")
```

Then the write failed with following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error closing multipart upload
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.uploadMultiParts(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:378)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.close(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:639)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:117)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:163)
```

Alternatively, I could write to HDFS first then use s3distcp to copy to S3, that said, just wonder how can I make direct writing to S3 work?

Thanks